# How can we change timer argument to accept double delay value instead of int?

Tags: java

I am new to java. I am trying to collect dynamic events at exponential inter-arrival time (which are not integers).

But I want my 'timer' value to be double, is there any alternative to make Timer Class to accept value which is double?

I tried using Timer ActionListerner like below:

```
double timer = data.getInterArrivalTime(0.5);
    timer1 = new Timer(timer, new DataCollection());
    timer1.start();
```

My DataCollection class is:

```
private class DataCollection implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        int eventValue =  data.poisson(25);
        valueListAtOrigin.addLast(eventValue);
        time = time + timer;
        timeListAtOrigin.addLast(time); 

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The timer only accurate to the nearest milli-second at best.  Even if you could set fractions of a milli-second, it wouldn't actually work this way.

The simplest thing to do is to round the time to the nearest `long` with a cast.

```
timer1 = new Timer((long) timer, new DataCollection());
```

---

BTW For your interest the code for Object.wait(long millis, int nanos) is

```
public final void wait(long timeout, int nanos) throws InterruptedException {
    if (timeout < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
    }

if (nanos >= 500000 || (nanos != 0 && timeout == 0)) {
    timeout++;
}

wait(timeout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Actually, I am trying to model a scenario where event is generated with Poisson Distribution with inter-arrival time given by exponential distribution. I need to catch all events with time when they are generated. My problem is I am not able to generate events as exactly as exponential time interval since the Timer Class accepts only integer argument. My waiting time should be given by exponential distribution. Anyway other way to do this without using Timer Class? I am stuck! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can only use simulated time as no real system will work this way.  You can add events to a PriorityQueue and events from this queue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake to use floating point numbers (float and double) instead of integer numbers (int and long). In your scenario, a time interval should be measured using an int or long , e.g. milliseconds.